# Can't return a string and a list from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to parse the `website address` of different agencies from it's landing page and the `location address` from it's inner page. What I can't understand is how can i return a `string` and a `list` at the same time in order for them to be reused in another function. To be clearer: I wish to return the `website address` and `list of links` from `collect_links()` function and reuse them in `get_info()` function. My current approach throws an error - `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

Tis is my attempt so far:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def collect_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    website = [soup.select_one("p.company-profile-website > a").get("href")]
    items = [urljoin(url,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select("[id^='company-'] .search-companies-result-info h2 > a")]
    return website,items

def get_info(website,link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    address = soup.select_one("p.footer-right").get_text(strip=True)
    print(website,address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/A"
    for item,link in collect_links(url):
        get_info(item,link)
```

***How can I return a string and a list from one function to another?***

PS I would like to be stick to the design I've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `websites` is a `list` with a single element string, not a string as you've enclosed it in `[]` literal. You need to drop `[]` to make it a string as no point making that a list.

After doing that, you can get the return value, and iterate over the links like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/A"
    website, links = collect_links(url) 
    for link in links:
        get_info(website, link)
```

Answer (score 1):

Main error in the code is in this link.

```
website = [soup.select_one("p.company-profile-website > a").get("href")]
```

This only returns one value:

```
http://www.autoskills-uk.com
```

Your function should be:

```
def collect_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    websites = [x.get("href") for x in soup.select("p.company-profile-website > a")]    #<============== Changed
    items = [urljoin(url,item.get("href")) for item in soup.select("[id^='company-'] .search-companies-result-info h2 > a")]
    return zip(websites, items)
```

Return as zip of websites and items.

Now you can list unpack `item` and `link` in the for loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.cv-library.co.uk/companies/agencies/A"
    for item,link in collect_links(url):
        get_info(item,link)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning two lists, one with one element and another, with many elements as a tuple, and try to iterator over this tuple, unpacking each list into two elements `item` and `link`.

I don't see, what you really want to do, but you should separate for-loop and return values:

```
website, links = collect_links(url)
for link in links:
    get_info(website[0], link)
```

Comment: Isn't `website` supposed to be a single element?